# Access to the coordinates of a 3D graphic inserted in a Tkinter.canvas

Tags: matplotlib, tkinter

I am very new in matplotlib and consequently I encounter some problems.. I try to insert a 3D graphic in a Tkinter canvas and I would like to get, (on click), the position of the mouse. The problem is that event.x and event.y return the position of the mouse in the canvas "base". Is it possible to get the (x,y,z) coordinates on the 3D graphic?
I saw that these coordinates are given in the toolbar, is there any possibility to access them?

Here is a part of the code I used

```
    fen1 = Tk.Tk()
      fen1.wm_title("Calcul des desorientation entre grain")
      fen1.bind("<Destroy>", destroy)
      canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=fen1)
      canvas.show()
      canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=Tk.TOP, fill=Tk.BOTH, expand=1)
      toolbar = NavigationToolbar2TkAgg(canvas,fen1)
      toolbar.update()
      canvas._tkcanvas.pack(side=Tk.TOP, fill=Tk.BOTH, expand=1)
```

...

I would be grateful if someone can help me.